# Checks made out to multiple parties with 'and'. How can I deposit it with one signature?

Tags: united-states, check, deposits, endorsement

I am receiving payments from a lawsuit in my favor, with three other plaintiffs.

The payments we are receiving are personal checks, made out to all off the plaintiffs with 'and' joining the names.

The defendant will not remove the other names, or use 'or' on the checks while making payments.

In order to retrieve all the signatures, the check would have to be mailed 350+ miles and make two stops.

Is there any possible way I can deposit the check with ONLY my signature?

Comment: Tried depositing it at the ATM?

Comment: My bank does not have a physical presence. It's almost entirely online. I could deposit it from my phone, but I'm worried about my bank or the other back rejecting it.

Comment: do they have an app? Many banks allow you to photograph the check with your phone to deposit it. (but with arbitrary $$$ limits)

Comment: They do, but I'm worried about repercussions from either bank or the person who wrote the check.

Comment: You're receiving one check each period which the four of you jointly deserve the proceeds?  Or you're each receiving a check separately per period with just what you deserve?  In the former case, I think the defendant likely is doing this precisely correctly.

Comment: The former. So our only option is to mail the check around every month?

Comment: Opening a joint account shared by the three people might work around this; I've certainly seen enough checks written to a couple deposited into their joint accounts with a single signature ... That does presume the three of you trust each other. If you don't, it might be possible to set up a joint escrow account with payments out of it managed by a trusted party. Has your lawyer offered any suggestions?

Comment: It was a small claims case, so no lawyer was involved. We do all trust each other, so a new joint bank account may be the way to go.

Comment: @Crazydog check that bank's regulations. Many banks will require all the people to sign to deposit it, even if this is a joint account. One reason would be to reduce chances of fraud when someone with the same name steals someone else's check. Having the persons' signature eliminates a chance of a claim for such a fraud.

Comment: @ Crazy Dog Have you been able to deposit to USAA with just one signature? I have a similar situation and also have USAA bank - I can deposit online which I am pretty sure would work but afraid they will review the scan, find just one signature and bounce the check.
Thanks!

Comment: @zema-struve We actually haven't tried. We've ended up just mailing the checks around, which has worked for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If some clerk at the bank misses it, you may be able. Technically you shouldn't be allowed to. All three have to sign.

Comment: I use USAA so I don't have a physical bank to go in to. I can deposit it from my phone, but I'm worried about one bank rejecting it. Additionally, the defendant has threatened legal action (although I'm not sure it would do anything) if we don't all sign the checks.

Comment: @Crazydog the defendant may have a case though. What's the problem mailing the check to the rest of the parties?

Comment: The problem is we are expecting about about 20 more checks, and it will be a nightmare mailing a check 350 miles, with two stops, every month, for nearly the next two years.

Comment: @Crazydog talk to the lawyer that represented you in the lawsuit to see how the payout provisions can be amended. The losing party has no incentive to make your life any less miserable, so yeah - you're stuck with this unless you can change the terms of the settlement payout. Judge approval may be required as well.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned that this was a high-trust situation where you all were trusting of each other and willing to open a bank account together.

Given that high trust environment, here's an unusual solution that may work for you.

Person B and Person C could each send a very limited power of attorney letter to Person A allowing Person A to sign checks from a certain party and deposit them into the account.   Person A could then wire/transfer/mail another check to Person B and Person C for the money.

It would take some effort to set up the limited power of attorney document, but then it would be easy for one person to deposit the checks and send the money around.

Answer (score 2):

The only alternative to having your very own monthly chain letter ("if you don't pass this letter on, you and three other people will lose money!") that I'm aware of is talking with a bank (you'll need to talk with a personal banker) or similar escrow service that will allow you to open an account jointly. The bank may or may not allow you to skip signing individually, but with shared responsibility for the account it may be possible. Effectively this is a limited partnership with a joint bank account, so only one person needs to have signing/withdrawal authority - but this may have tax implications and other complications, too!

What you really want to do is have an effective escrow service: one party accepts a payment on behalf of multiple people, and then that party distributes the money as appropriate to the signed agreements. If - and it's definitely an IF - a company/service would agree to such a thing, you could just sign an agreement once and forward the check to them. They will cash it using their established legal/banking agreements and in accordance with existing regulations, and then distribute the money as agreed.

There will be a fee for this service, of course, and it is subject to this actually being something an escrow company is willing and able to do for you.

Alternatively, if there is only four or five of you and you are all on good terms, then I would spend just a little time setting up a system so this can be quick and relatively painless. Get yourself postage paid envelopes and print out some address labels for everyone, and send these out to everyone.

Have the check sent to person A. A signs the check, puts it into prepaid and pre-addressed envelope and sticks it in mail box (if you are worried about it getting lost you may want to spring for a tracking/certified mailing) to person B. B repeats and sends to C, C sends to D, and D signs and puts in the bank and distributes the funds as appropriate. 5 minutes of time per month and two weeks of calendar waiting (if you don't spring for express shipping), and then you have your money.

In legal matters it really often is better to get permission rather than seek forgiveness, so I would strongly encourage you to talk with a lawyer and/or a banker before doing anything other than the manual mailing method, as you've been planning.

In short, the legal system is inconvenient, grinding, and often deeply antiquated, so don't expect anything terribly convenient or time-saving from it - it's almost as if most of the people involved get paid by the hour, or something, inside a system that seems to practically worship paper and tradition. Go figure!